# adding 16 bits registers

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, cpu-registers

I have this code

```
addInt:
        add cx, bx
        cmp cx, 0FFFFh
        JBE convert
```

I'm trying to add cx and bx registers, each have the same value of `FFFF`, instead of getting `1FFFE`, I get only `FFFE`, and when I try to use `JBE` to jump to convert loop, JBE istruction does nothing because `ecx` register now contain only `FFFE`, but not `1FFF`, so how can i fix this code to make `ecx` contain 1FFFE and how do I compare to check if it is still 16 bits or not. I cannot use any 32 bits registers which make thing more complicated

Thank in advance

Comment: The maximum value a 16 bit register can contain is `FFFF`..

Comment: Why can't you use 32-bit registers? (This would be a lot easier if you used `ecx`.)

Comment: It may possibly help if you check `OF` (overflow flag) in `FLAGS` after the `add` instruction.

Comment: overflow would not work since i can only use 16 bits registers, it will never get over flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addInt:

    clc            ;clear carry flag

    add cx,bx

    jnc convert    ;jump no carry

    cmp cx,FFFEh   ;This now needs to be true, only FFFF+FFFF will succeed

                    because it generates a carry AND matches the cmp

    Jnz convert    ;will let it through
```

This will work, but it's very limited and simplistic

To "count" the carry use adc dx,0 inserted after jnc convert

The carry flag is set if a register goes round the clock, so it acts like a single bit

ADD FFFF+2 will set it off, giving you a +ve carry flag and 0001 in the register

You can store that flag count in a separate register with adc [other register],0

using the carry flag allows you slap your registers together to count up to something like

1,208,741,363,432,547,555,475,424 with 4x16 bit registers

which is quite a lot and miles better than 65,534

Comment: then if i want to compare any sum that is larger than the value of 16 bits how should i do that?

Comment: The first part does that, jnc

Comment: If you want to compare two separate numbers both larger than 16 bits in a 16 bit environment then you are going to need to learn how to use multiple registers