# test if hexadecimal number is in range of 16 bits register

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, addition, cpu-registers

```
addInt:
        clc
        mov ax, cx
        add ax, bx
            JNC convert
```

how would i be able to test if the sum is in range of  16 bits, since if I add using 16 bits register the result does not show the carry over value even if the sum is greater than 16 bits,  OF will not work either since it will never become overflow due to the use of 16 bits registers. How should i continue this code to make it jump to convert loop. for example if I have `FFFF + FFFE`, the sum will be `1FFFD`, but the eax register will only show `FFFD`, without the carry over 1
thank in advance for helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding 16 bits registers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641366/adding-16-bits-registers)

Comment: Can you instead tell us what you're *actually* trying to do? You state that you can't use the 32-bit registers, but you're referring to `eax`.

Comment: yes, I actually re-posting that question because i don't know how to renew the question, What i was trying to do is check if the sum is larger than 16 bits, but I'm only allow to use 16 bits register for my assignment, It is easy to do this with 32 bits register, but with the 16 bits, you don't see the upper half of eax after you add which make it harder

Comment: You're showing code that tests the carry flag - this is what you should be doing. Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: yes, because im using 16 bits register so it does not show the carry over value, so for example when i add FFFF + FFFE, i would get FFFD instead of 1FFFD

Comment: Are you in 16-bit or 32-bit mode?

Comment: The carry flag should be set if you add two registers with values that add up to be > 0xFFFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to tell after the `add` instruction if your resultant value is larger than 16-bits.

> The ADD instruction performs integer addition. It evaluates the result for both signed 
>   and unsigned integer operands and sets the OF and CF flags to indicate a carry (overflow) in the signed or unsigned result, respectively. The SF flag indicates the sign of 
>   the signed result.

Since you appear to be dealing with unsigned 16-bit values, you should look at `CF`, the carry flag after the addition:

```
addInt:
    clc
    mov ax, cx
    add ax, bx                ; Sets CF if result is larger than 16-bits
    jc .larger_than_16_bits
```

Comment: thank very much , this is the simpliest way to do it, I think i was over estimating the problem and make it seems harder than it should be

Comment: Note that I basically just explained your own code to you. That means that you should always seek to have a complete understanding of what your code is doing.